# How to use mylatexformat to precompile headers with lualatex?

Tags: luatex, compilation-error, format-files

I would like to use `mylatexformat` to precompile headers without having to put them into a separate `preamble.tex`.

This works fine with `pdflatex` - can I do the same with `lualatex`? This is what I have tried in `bug.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{datetime2}
% \usepackage{microtype}
% \usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\DTMnow
\end{document}
```

I build this file using

```
lualatex -ini -jobname="bug" "&lualatex" mylatexformat.ltx bug.tex
lualatex --fmt="bug.fmt" bug.tex
```

This works fine.

However, enabling various packages leads to very different errors:

- `microtype`:

```
(/home/bers/opt/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/mt-LatinModernRom
an.cfg[\directlua]:1: attempt to index a nil value (global 'microtype')
stack traceback:
        [\directlua]:1: in main chunk.
MT@ifstreq ...{microtype.if_str_eq([[#1]],[[#2]])}
                                                  endcsname 
l.105    }
```

- `tikz`:

```
(/home/bers/opt/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cf
g)) [1{/home/bers/opt/texlive/2020/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.m
ap}]
! error:  (pdf backend): referenced object has wrong type others; should be obj

!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Comment: it is tricky as you can not dump any Lua state (including opentype font data) in the format, so unless the package is written to easily defer any lua code it typically can not be dumped in the format.

Comment: Short answer: Don't. You can't dump the Lua state in the format. There are some answers on the site which tackle this by moving the Lua bits after the format, but that does only work for some packages, afaik.